# there is no region in region server,HBase

Tags: bigdata, hbase, region

my hbase version
2.1.0+cdh6.3.2

one day one region is down, then I restarted it.
After it, I find there is no region in it;
[image]

I try to add balancer in `hbase-site.xml` of Master, like that
[image]

and restart Hbase, but no working.

Anyone has suggestion about it, please.

Comment: Hello Peng , Have you checked if there are any regions in transition. Can you check if you can run balance_switch and balancer commands from the hbase shell and see if the reassignment happens

Comment: Thank for your replay.These is no regions in transition.'balancer_enable' is true.When I  run command 'balancer' ,it return false.finally, I backup data,and reinstall CDH.

Comment: Interesting , balancer returns false in case there are regions in transition. Would be interesting to see why that is the case